# List comprehension with repeated computation

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am currently playing about with Project Euler problem 53 in Python. The solution is trivially simple but involved the following list comprehension:

```
[scipy.misc.comb(n, r, exact=True)
 for n in range(1,maxn+1)
 for r in range(0,n+1)
 if scipy.misc.comb(n, r, exact=True) > threshold]
```

My concern is though that the scipy.misc.comb() function would be called twice per iteration. Is there any way of replacing one or other occurrence of it with some sort of reference; alternatively is the interpreter smart enough to realise that the two instances will evaluate to the same thing?

Comment: The interpreter is not smart enough to work out that both function calls will evaluate to the same thing. However, the function itself might be written to cache results.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: rather, the interpreter is smart enough to know that it cannot possibly know that the same results will be produced each time the function is called, even with the same arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the `scipy.misc.comb()` function into a generator expression:

```
[comb for comb in 
    (scipy.misc.comb(n, r, exact=True) 
     for n in range(1,maxn+1) for r in range(0,n+1))
 if comb > threshold]
```

and it'll be calculated just once per iteration over the generator.

Putting the generator expression into a separate variable may make this clearer:

```
calculated = (scipy.misc.comb(n, r, exact=True) 
              for n in range(1,maxn+1) for r in range(0,n+1))
[comb for comb in calculated if comb > threshold]
```

See this as a conveyor belt; the `calculated` generator is only producing its output as the list comprehension iterates over it.